# Only allow a CA certificate to be used for a VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, certificate

My company recently added an IKEv2 VPN with a self-signed certificate. They asked us to add a self-issued root certificate to our computers. I use my private computer at work so naturally I am cautious about adding untrusted CA certificates. Is there any way to allow this cert to only be used for VPN connections? Even better, only for this single connection that I use for work.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done (I'm not saying it can't, I just don't know how, due to the problems with the vpn being at layer 3, and the application not having that level of visiblity) however maybe you could install the cert in a VM, and run the browser (possibly in seamless mode) to use it? Then only use that browser for work related stuff. (The cert will allow them to see all your traffic/passwords/etc via that browser).

Comment: What OS are you using and what IKEv2 client are you using?

Comment: Our whole infrastructure is behind that VPN so it isn't as easy unfortunately. I use Windows 10 and the built in IKEv2 client.